# Is receiving a signal the same as sampling a signal?

Tags: terminology

Is receiving a signal the same as sampling a signal?

When a person or a machine "receives" a signal, is that the same as "sampling" it?

Comment: No. Both words have a "normal" English meaning and describe fundamentally different things. Have you looked them up? If so, which questions remained so that you came here to ask?

Comment: What did you mean by looking them up? In English I can say that a machine received something and responded somehow or that I have sampled something and concluded something, what else is there to "look up"?

Comment: yes, exactly, look up in a dictionary. And it seems you *know* the meaning of "to sample" and "to receive". So, what is the question that remains?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I want to know if "sampling" is distinct from "receiving" in signal processing culture or "slang", that's all. I would gamble they aren't but the world is full of surprises.

Comment: They are distinct. You can look up their  definitions! They are simply very different things.

Comment: @mmmm Do you suggest me to look up for their colloquial definitions or their Signal Processing definitions ? If the SP definitions are similar to those in colloquial language then why should I look up these term?

Comment: @semo there seems to be no relevant difference between colloquial and sp terminology here. Why do you assume there would be and how would asking us beer better then (again) just consulting Wikipedia? You might just as well ask whether a dog and a horse are the same thing in farming...

Comment: @mmmm I assume because colloquial can be different than field-specific and not once I found terminology in SP tricky or ambiguous compared to other STEM fields. I reject the comparison you have made in the last part of your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When a person or a machine "receives" a signal, is that the same as "sampling" it?

No.

There are plenty of analog receivers out there. "sampling" refers to the process of time discretization: i.e. turning a continuous signal into a string of numbers.

Receiving and sampling are completely orthogonal. You can receive with and without sampling, and you can sample with and without receiving.

Comment: Just one thing I miss, how can one sample a signal without receiving it?

Comment: Signals exist outside receivers, so why would you assume you would need to receive a signal to sample it? Apply Occam's razor whenever asking something like that.